# group_by() and summarise() returning na values

Tags: dplyr, group-by, summarize

This is the dataset I'm working with:

```
#coverboard
Period      EEM.or.NCOS  Habitat  Date      Species             Count
2020-2022    EEM     CSS   100     1/1/20      Alligator.Lizard  0
2020-2022    EEM     TS    200     1/1/20      Garter.Snake      1
2020-2022    NCOS    TS    NA      1/1/20      Field.Mouse       0
2020-2022    NCOS    AR    150     1/1/20      Field.Mouse       2
```

there are no NA values at all, and all the counts are an integer. But when i run this code

```
coverboard_loc <- coverboard%>%
      group_by(EEM.or.NCOS, Species) %>% summarise(Encounter_mean =
    mean(count), dev = sd(count))
```

I get this result back

```
EEM Ringneck.Snake 0.0058139535

EEM Slender.Salamander 0.0170542636

EEM Western.Fence.Lizard 0.2534883721

EEM Western.Skink NA

Ellwood Alligator.Lizard 0.0000000000

Ellwood California.Vole 0.0113636364
```

And it's not that the mean is zero and that's creating an error, because for some the mean *is* 0 and it lists it. Not sure what in the data or code is messed up but something's wrong.

Comment: Typo? `Count` versus `mean(count)` and `sd(count)`.

Comment: In which mean column do you get the NA : `Encounter_mean` or `dev` ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `count` by `Count`

```r
coverboard_loc <- coverboard%>%
      group_by(EEM.or.NCOS, Species) %>% summarise(Encounter_mean =
    mean(Count), dev = sd(Count)) # PART THAT MUST BE EDITED
```

Answer taken from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015313/group-by-and-summarise-returning-na-values#comment128960093_73015313)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it-- I tried that and got the same result

Comment: I just understood the trouble here. You got `EEM Western.Skink NA` because there is no such combination in the `coverboard` dataframe

Comment: the dataframe i posted isn't the entire one-- the real one is thousands of entries. I just posted a sample from it

Comment: I will post an answer to avoid the NA

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(head(coverboard))`, so I can have some data ?

Comment: structure(list(Period = c("2020-2022", "2020-2022", "2020-2022", 
"2020-2022", "2020-2022", "2020-2022"), EEM.or.NCOS = c("EEM", 
"EEM", "EEM", "EEM", "EEM", "EEM"), Habitat = c("Coastal Sage Scrub", 
"Coastal Sage Scrub", "Coastal Sage Scrub", "Coastal Sage Scrub", 
"Coastal Sage Scrub", "Coastal Sage Scrub"), Date = c("10/5/20", 
"10/5/20", "10/5/20", "10/5/20", "10/5/20", "10/5/20"), Species = c("Deer.Mouse", 
"Garter.Snake", "Gopher.Snake", "Pacific.Tree.Frog", "California.Vole", 
"Ringneck.Snake"), count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),

Comment: row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 0):

You wil get `NA` in the `dev` column if there is only one row for a given group `(EEM.or.NCOS, Species)`, indeed :
**The `sd` function returns `NA` for a vector of length 1**. I have never understood this beahviour, it should return `0`, it would be more coherent if so.
So I don't think that your code produces a surprinsing output

```r
#The sd function behaves strangely
sd(c(1))
#> [1] NA
sd(c(1,1))
#> [1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace `NA` by `0`

```r
library(dplyr); library(tidyr) 
coverboard_loc <- coverboard %>%
  group_by(EEM.or.NCOS, Species) %>% 
  summarise(Encounter_mean = mean(count), dev = sd(count)) %>% 
  mutate(dev = replace_na(dev, 0)) # replace `NA` by `0`
```